# javascript_include_tag not working properly inside a partial in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2, renderpartial

i am using simple_nested_form and i hav this in my customer bill form

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @customer_bill do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_messages %>

 <%= f.label :employee_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :employee_id, Employee.all,:id,:name, {:prompt => "Select Employee"}, :style => 'width:205px;' %><br />

            <%= f.label :date %>
            <%= f.datepicker :date, :dateFormat => 'dd MM, yy',  :showOn => "both", :buttonImage => "../assets/calendar.gif", :buttonImageOnly => true, :changeMonth => true, :changeYear => true, :placeholder => "Click on the Calender" %><br/>          

 <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add Product", :customer_bill_line_items %> </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

After i click the "add product"  the following partial is been rendered

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'calculations' %>
     <hr/> 
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :customer_bill_id %>

    <%= f.label :product_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :product_id,Product.all,:id,:title, :prompt => "Select a Product", :style => 'width:150px;' %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= f.link_to_remove "Remove Product"%>
    <br/>

     <p class="fields">
<%= f.input :price, :class =>"price" %>
<br/>
<%= f.input :quantity, :class =>"qty" %><br/>

<%= f.input :amount, :class =>"amount"%><br/>
</p>
```

And i have this in my Calculations.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".price, .qty").keyup(function() {
        var p = jQuery(".price").val();
        var q = jQuery(".qty").val();
        jQuery(".amount").val(q * p);
    });
});
```

​

Now the Problem is First time wen i click "Add products" and i Enter 'price' and 'quantity' the amount is calculated inside the js file and is displayed in the 'amount' field and wen i click add product for second time, the calculations of the first is been rendered, it seems the js file is displaying the value calculated first time in every 'amount' field

What seems to be the problem? What can i do to make proper Calculations happen everytime i call the partial? need help urgently. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your "add product" partial is rendered the second time, you have some elements on the page with duplicate `id` values (`price`, `qty`, `amount`). This is invalid HTML, and jQuery won't be able to tell which ones you mean to bind `keyup` to.

Try rewriting your partial and jQuery to avoid this problem. Either generate properly unique ids, or hook your `keyup` onto a different property (perhaps a class?). If you go for the latter route, you could also consider putting the jQuery into the page as a `live` call, rather than adding new `keyup` bindings for each new product.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Chowlett, m actually new to this, just been following railcasts and other forums to implement this. Can u tell how i can create unique id's??

Comment: @Chowlett-i replaced the 'id' and put it as 'class', the problem is almost resolved. Now From second time the partial is called, Amount calculated in the first time partial is coming!! dunno what to do abt that. Any light on that??

Comment: I also used live instead of keyup, its not helping!

Comment: You need to make sure you're calculating based on the right instance of the field. Instead of re-calling `jQuery('.price')` inside your handle, traverse the DOM from `this` to make sure you get the `.price` and `.qty` that are children of the same parent.

Comment: Can u please post the code Chowlett or any link to notes where i can understand functions properly, am getting confused, sorry...

Comment: [Fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/E9u53/) - hopefully that clears things up a bit. Docs on the DOM traversal are [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

Comment: Thanks buddy, Now i understand DOM better, but the code u posted isnt working for some reason, Amount is not coming only, some problem with gem dependency???? i have this `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".price, .qty").keyup(function() {
        var parent = $(this).closest('.fields');
        var p = parent.find(".price").val();
        var q = parent.find(".qty").val();
        parent.find(".amount").val(q * p);
    });
})` and this

Comment: `<p class="fields">
 <%= f.label :price, "price"%> 
<%= f.text_field :price, :size=>20, :class =>"price" %>
<br/>

<%= f.label :quantity, "Quantity"%>
<%= f.text_field :quantity, :size=>20, :class =>"qty" %><br/>

<%= f.label :amount, "Amount"%>
<%= f.text_field :amount, :size=>20, :class =>"amount"%><br/>
</p>`

Comment: I think it's that `jQuery(document).ready(` won't fire if you add it after the page loaded. Try taking the Javascript out of the partial, render it into the page normally, and replace `.keyup` with `.live('keyup')` ([live](http://api.jquery.com/live/))